# maven project fails to import a class in the same package

Tags: java

Result of `mvn assembly:assembly`

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project WordCount: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
> [ERROR] /Users/user/practice/storm-word-count/WordCount/src/main/java/com/c3/example/RandomSentenceSpout.java:[13,8] duplicate class: RandomSentenceSpout
> [ERROR] /Users/user/practice/storm-word-count/WordCount/src/main/java/com/c3/example/WordCountTopology.java:[18,39] cannot access com.c3.example.RandomSentenceSpout
> [ERROR]   bad source file: /Users/user/practice/storm-word-count/WordCount/src/main/java/com/c3/example/RandomSentenceSpout.java
> [ERROR]     file does not contain class com.c3.example.RandomSentenceSpout
> [ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

source files

```
$ cat /Users/user/practice/storm-word-count/WordCount/src/main/java/com/c3/example/RandomSentenceSpout.java
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;
import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

//This spout randomly emits sentences
public class RandomSentenceSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    //Collector used to emit output
    SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
    //Used to generate a random number
    Random _rand;

    //Open is called when an instance of the class is created
    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    //Set the instance collector to the one passed in
        _collector = collector;
        //For randomness
        _rand = new Random();
    }

    //Emit data to the stream
    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
    //Sleep for a bit
        Utils.sleep(100);
        //The sentences that are randomly emitted
        String[] sentences = new String[]{ "the cow jumped over the moon", "an apple a day keeps the doctor away",
            "four score and seven years ago", "snow white and the seven dwarfs", "i am at two with nature" };
        //Randomly pick a sentence
        String sentence = sentences[_rand.nextInt(sentences.length)];
        //Emit the sentence
        _collector.emit(new Values(sentence));
    }

    //Ack is not implemented since this is a basic example
    @Override
    public void ack(Object id) {
    }
    //There are a variety of bolt types. In this case, use BaseBasicBolt

    //Fail is not implemented since this is a basic example
    @Override
    public void fail(Object id) {
    }

    //Declare the output fields. In this case, an sentence
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("sentence"));
    }
}
```

```
cat /Users/user/practice/storm-word-count/WordCount/src/main/java/com/c3/example/WordCountTopology.java
package com.c3.example;

import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;


public class WordCountTopology {

    //Entry point for the topology
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Used to build the topology
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        //Add the spout, with a name of 'spout'
        //and parallelism hint of 5 executors
        builder.setSpout("spout", new RandomSentenceSpout(), 5);
        //Add the SplitSentence bolt, with a name of 'split'
        //and parallelism hint of 8 executors
        //shufflegrouping subscribes to the spout, and equally distributes
        //tuples (sentences) across instances of the SplitSentence bolt
        builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
        //Add the counter, with a name of 'count'
        //and parallelism hint of 12 executors
        //fieldsgrouping subscribes to the split bolt, and
        //ensures that the same word is sent to the same instance (group by field 'word')
        builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));

        //new configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        //Set to false to disable debug information when
        // running in production on a cluster
        conf.setDebug(false);

        //If there are arguments, we are running on a cluster
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        //parallelism hint to set the number of workers
        conf.setNumWorkers(3);
        //submit the topology
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
        }
        //Otherwise, we are running locally
        else {
        //Cap the maximum number of executors that can be spawned
        //for a component to 3
        conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);
        //LocalCluster is used to run locally
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        //submit the topology
        cluster.submitTopology("word-count", conf, builder.createTopology());
        //sleep
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        //shut down the cluster
        cluster.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get why it fails to find RandomSentenceSpout class.

Why is it searching for `com.c3.example.RandomSentenceSpout` class?

Comment: Your source file `RandomSentenceSpout.java` seems to be missing a package statement: `package com.c3.example;`

Comment: Okay... it was the problem... Thank you!!